# How to get a text file into variable?

Tags: bash, variables

How can I get a text file with contents like this `01:23:45:67:89:ab` into the variable `$LastMAC`? I already tried a few variations, with cat but not luck. I tried to use the LastMAC=$(cat LastMAC.txt, also tried to use LastMAC=`cat LastMAC.txt' and there is no error code, but the prompt just shows a blinking cursor, and does nothing.

Comment: Please show your actual corpus, your sample code, and any error messages you may have encountered.

Comment: I tried to use the LastMAC=$(cat LastMAC.txt, also tried to use LastMAC=`cat LastMAC.txt' and there is no error code, but it just hangs

Comment: Both the examples you tried work for me. What code are you using to prove that your technique is failing? If it works, then it will appear nothing happens. Use `echo $LastMAC` to test.

Comment: Well the way the script is written, is after it does that line of code it echos $LastMAC, but all it does is just sit there and cursor blinks

Comment: Did you omit the trailing backtick and closing `)` on purpose? It should be `LastMAC="$(cat LastMAC.txt)"` with the quotes to prevent word-splitting. And `echo "$LastMAC"`. And please post the actual script, there is no point guessing what you're doing.

Comment: #Loading Variables to Compare, from scan "NewMAC" and LastMACFile "LastMAC"

NewMAC=$(awk '/^[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9][.][0-9]+/ {print $2}' MACScanResults.txt)

LastMAC=$(< LastMAC.txt)

echo $LastMAC

Comment: @user3525621 Not post your script here but post it in question window.

Comment: @user3525621 Also post content of `MACScanResults.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

It most likely did work.  On the next line, add:

```
echo $LastMAC
```

to see it.

By the way, $( ) is preferred over using back quotes for command substitution.  If you ever have to nest command substitutions, you'll see why.

Comment: Well the way the script is written, is after it does that line of code it echos $LastMAC, but all it does is just sit there and cursor blinks

Comment: And LastMAC.txt is in the current directory and indeed does contain what you expect?

Comment: Oh I think I see a bug.  make sure you have a close paren after the filename: LastMAC=$(cat LastMAC.txt)

Comment: the file is in the same directory that I am working in, and if I type cat LastMAC.txt, then in the terminal I can see the contents, but is wont work when I try and get the text into a variable

Comment: Yeah you need a closing paren

Comment: I have a closing paren, and still nothing

Comment: That was a typo on the paste, the code has both ()

Comment: well it works for me.  humph

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the file LastMax.txt has the content you want like `01:23:45:67:89:ab`
then run this code

```
LastMAC=$(cat LastMAC.txt)
```

That line first reads the file LastMAC.txt and assigns the output to the variable $LastMAC. To display the contents of the variable $LastMAC run this command

```
echo $LastMAC
```

Comment: From the bash manpage: *The command substitution `$(cat file)` can be replaced by the equivalent but faster `$(< file)`.*